# Postgres - improving an update statement to a table with large set of data

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with daily partitions

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
    record_id       BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    events          TEXT,
    status          int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    insert_time     bigint DEFAULT date_part('epoch'::text, timezone('utc'::text, now())),
    event_source    varchar(255),
    row_insert_time timestamp not null default current_timestamp
) PARTITION BY RANGE (row_insert_time);


create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_21 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-21 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-22 00:00:00')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_22 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-22 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-23 00:00:00')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_23 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-23 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-24 00:00:00')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_24 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-24 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-25 00:00:00')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_25 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-25 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-26 00:00:00')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_26 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-26 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-27 00:00:00')
```

When I run an explain plan for the following update statement, it seems to be scanning all partitions.

```
explain UPDATE events SET status = 1 WHERE row_insert_time > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR' and row_insert_time < NOW() and record_id = 1282695;
```

I would have thought using row_insert_time in the where clause would limit number of partitions it scans. What can I do to limit the update from scanning all partitions to perform the update?

Comment: There is something strange/wrong in your partitions, your `from` and `to` are equal. Just one second per day is allowed for each partition?

Comment: That was a copy and paste error. I have fixed the the partition end dates

Answer (score 0):

Planning-time pruning is not done here, because the planner doesn't know what the value of now() will be at the time the query is executed.  But run-time pruning is done, as you can see if you do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`.